# kafka python - What is the right way to find new kafka topics that a consumer has not been yet subscribed to?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python, confluent-kafka-python

I am new to the kafka world and trying to do the following for a kafka consumer in python

1. get a list of all kafka topics.
2. get a list of topics a consumer has subscribed to.
3. subscribe to new topics (that have not yet been subscribed to).

Note: I am ok to use either confluent-kafka / kafka-python library to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you created your Consumer with `kafka-python`

```py
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
 bootstrap_servers = 'hostname:port',
)
```

you can review the list of topics available with

```py
consumer.topics()
```

when you subscribe to topics, you can review the consumer subscriptions with

```py
consumer.subscription()
```

You can do one minus the other to find the topics you still need to subscribe to and then you can do so with

```
consumer.subscribe(topics=[list_of_topic_names])
```

Comment: Looks like subscribe() does not allow incremental topic subscription. The list provided in subscribe() fn will replace the existing subscription list.

If so, is there any side effect for re-subscribing to the same topics?

More info: https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.subscribe